# How do I achieve this task, If I insert or delete a row in one sheet it should automatically insert or delete same row in other sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I had 2 sheets in workbook.say sheet1 and sheet2. If suppose I insert a blank row in sheet1 at row number 8, then it should automatically add a blank row in row number 8 in sheet2.

The same applies for deletion as well.
Sheet1 will be used by user and sheet2 will be hidden from user.

If user delete a row from sheet1 then it should refelect in sheet2, that is what I want.

Can I do this using a macro?

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance…

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL? Can you post the code you have already?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need an anchor in the sheet to be able to know if the change implied deletion/insertion. Like a named range.

Comment: You can use the Worksheet Change event to detect the insertion or deletion.  If it's a deletion, then the target range will be blank, but if it's a deletion, there will be text there, unless you deleted the last row.  Once you determine what change was made, it's fairly easy reproduce it on the other sheet. (i.e. sh.range ("A14").entirerow.delete)

Comment: I have removed the mySQL tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would work with something like this

```
Private intPrevRows As Integer

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    intPrevRows = UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If UsedRange.Rows.Count < intPrevRows Then
        MsgBox "deleted"
    ElseIf UsedRange.Rows.Count > intPrevRows Then
        MsgBox "added"
    End If
    intPrevRows = UsedRange.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,
But I want exact location of inserted or deleted row.

Comment: Look at the target maybe, you'll have to do a bit to :)